# Use app.get for variable and null

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a middle-layer for an existing webpage. I want a single controller that does the same thing for all urls and also allows me to capture the first parameter. I have the following urls:

```
/
/ask
/1234
/1234/slug-for-page
```

1234 is a random number

I know I can do

```
app.get('/:method', parse);
```

to capture `"ask"` and `"/1234"`, but I need something that allows me to capture all of the samples above and also captures the variables.

Comment: Uhm, `app.get('/:method/:slug', parse);`

Comment: Or just `app.get('*' ...` and figure out the URL parts inside the route

Comment: the first example won't work as it won't catch `/` for example...

Comment: Well, that's why you have routes, to catch different URL's, if you don't want routes, just don't use them, you can use a "catch-all" callback and figure out everything for yourself, even it seems like a strange thing to do